# Баннер с тестом

Tags: php, тестирование, javascript

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой должен быть код (php или javascript) у блока, в котором вопрос и три варианта ответов. При выборе ответа в этом же блоке появляется второй вопрос и соответствующие варианты ответа. Так же считается количество верных ответов и происходит переход по соответствующей баллам ссылке.

Comment: Что значит "*какой должен быть код*"? Вы интересуетесь тем, какие средства лучше использовать для вашей задачи? Можно только PHP, можно только JS, а можно и то, и другое вместе.

Comment: Язык не важен, нужен именно код. С HTML и СSS всё понятно, а что с функциями нет.

Answer (score 1):

1)Если пхп то пункты ответа выводить ссылками.

```
Вопрос 1

<a href='index.php?question=1&answer=1>ответ 1</a>
<a href='index.php?question=1&answer=2>ответ 2</a>
```

На странице приёмщике проверять наличие и значения GET['question'] и GET['answer']
и от этого уже танцевать.

2) Если js то удобней будет использовать библиотеку jquery. Принимать ответ можно по действию click на варианте ответа. Дальше уже как пожелаете(или как умеете) поступать. Или средствами js подсчитывать количество правильных ответов (но в таком случае открыв исходный код можно будет подсмотреть ответы), или через ajax  передавать номер вопроса и номер варианта ответа обработчику php, после чего загружать в блок с вопросом и ответами следующий блок вопроса.

Comment: Спасибо! Буду пытаться.

Comment: Посмотрите в сети скрипты опросов.